# Is this a valid proof that this function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration, step-function

The question states:

> Define the function (where $n$ is in the positive integers)
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x,  & \text{if $x=\frac{1}{n^2}$} \\
> 0, & \text{if $x\neq\frac{1}{n^2}$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Prove that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and that $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=0$.

The textbook solutions uses the Riemann criterion to prove this.

My proof, on the other hand, went as follows:

Define a partition $P$ of $[0,1]$. $P=\{0,\dots,\frac{1}{n^2},\dots,1\}$. Then $n$ is constant on each open subinterval $(x_{k-1},x_k)$ of $P$. Moreover, $f(x)=0$ on all open subintervals of $P$. Hence $f$ is integrable. We then have $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\sum0\times(x_k-x_{k-1})=0$.

Using the Riemann criterion seems to me like 'overkill' given that this seems to me to be a step function, however I may be wrong, of course. Could anyone tell me if this is a valid proof, or must I use more sophisticated techniques like in the textbook?

Comment: I don't understand the definiton of $P$. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: It sounds like $P=\{ 1/n^2 : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, that is basically what I mean, but as an example if $n=2$, $P$ could be $\{0,\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{2^2},1\}$  or $\{0,\frac{1}{4},1\}$ As long as it includes $\frac{1}{n^2}$ it should be sufficient as the function is constant everywhere else, right?

Comment: This really seems to me to be crying out for Lesbague integration.  Were we can say that the set $\{x:x=\frac 1{n^2}\}$ is of measure $0.$

Comment: $n$ is not fixed here, so your statement doesn't make sense. What you seem to mean is that you are considering the sequence of partitions $P_N=\{ 1/n^2 : n=1,2,\dots,N \} \cup \{ 0 \}$. This sequence won't really save you because you aren't narrowing down the subintervals around the points $1/n^2$.

Comment: @Ian I didn't realize $n$ wasn't fixed. Now that makes more sense, thank you!

Comment: @DougM: to me it cries out even louder for the Henstock-Kurzweil gauge integral. Sadly, the gauge integral seems to be out of pedagogical favour, despite its many advantages.